# Android iteration error due to integer assignment

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to iterate over a 26 textViews (one for every letter of the alphabet). Below is what I tried and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.id.A"".
```

I know the problem is how I assigning the integer but not sure how to correct.

```
private void setupKeyBoard() {

    for(char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z';letter ++){

        int letterID = Integer.parseInt("R.id."+ letter); //This line is my issue
        Log.e("LetterID", Integer.toString(letterID));

        final TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(letterID);

        textView.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setText(letter);
        final char finalLetter = letter;

        textView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkGuess(finalLetter);
                textView.setClickable(false);
                textView.setAlpha((float) .1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to parse the string itself. "R.id.A" is not an integer; it's the name of a resource. You *actually* want to find the integer associated with the resource - you'll need reflection to do that, I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` does not what you are looking for.

What you want to achieve can be done using [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
int letterID = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(letter), "id", getPackageName());
```

Note that this is rather slow. Your best bet is probably to store those ids in an `int` array and loop through it.

```
int[] arr = {R.id.A, R.id.B, ... };

for(char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z';letter ++){
    final TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(arr[letter-'A']);
    .....
}
```

Comment: int letterID = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(letter), "id", getActivity().getPackageName());  I get ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.greui.app/com.example.greui.app.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x41.... Is converting my letter id to lower case?

Comment: Thank you Ill do the array. Much better idea not sure why the getResources as not working? I will go implement the array now.

Comment: @Jethro_Orange `getResources` is working. Your problem is probably `textView.setText(letter);` which have to be `textView.setText(String.valueOf(letter));`

Comment: Wow that was a stupid mistake. Thanks your solution is working. Sometimes it feels like I am pounding my head against a brick  wall...